# Accessing value of a Nullable type Implicitly and Explicitly

Tags: c#

Is there any difference when a `Nullable<int>` is accessed implicitly and explicitly?

```
    Nullable<int> x = 10;
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", x.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", (int)x);
```

Both print 10, but i want to know if there is any specific preference to use one over the other.

Comment: In the context of `String.Format` I wouldn't use either... just use `x`, i.e.: `Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", x);`

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad Won't they throw different exceptions? I'd expect one to throw a null ref and the other an invalid cast?

Comment: @Liath yes, if `x.HasValue` is false, `x.Value` will generate an [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Liath both throw System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: @canon I think that's probably the best answer we're going to get - go for it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explicit cast operator is defined as follows:

```
public static explicit operator T(T? value)
{
    return value.Value;
}
```

So actually, there is no difference at all, because it uses `Value` property anyway.

It's also well described on MSDN: [Nullable Explicit Conversion (Nullable to T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131345%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `T`
>
> The value of the `Value` property for the *`value`* parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is exactly no difference, both statements produce identical `IL` code

```
IL_0021:  nop
IL_0022:  ldstr      "Value: {0}"
IL_0027:  ldloca.s   x
IL_0029:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_Value()
IL_002e:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0033:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
```

Which make sense, as both will call the `Value` property anyway (as mentioned by @MarcinJuraszek).

If you are just looking for a safe call to access the value and you're not interested in the `null` part I would go with:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", x.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't agree with `GetValueOrDefault` suggestion. I would rather use `x.ToString()` to avoid: an exception from `Value` property, boxing operation on `WriteLine` call and `0` printed for both `(int?)0` and `(int?)null`.

Comment: The `x.ToString()` will be nicer indeed. But I don't like seeing `Value: `  as opposed to `Value: 0` in the console/logs - that's why I've mentioned `GetValueOrDefault` for display purposes.

Answer (score -1):

Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", (int)X) will unbox x which means it will fail if x is null. You can use the HasValue property on nullable types to check.

Comment: It is not unboxing anything; there is no boxed value to begin with.  Also, this doesn't explain the difference between the two methods of accessing the value.

Comment: Apologies that was incorrect. There is no unboxing in that scenario.